# TypeORM relation with a field apart from id

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, typeorm

I wanted to create a one-to-many relation in TypeORM with a field other than id, the usual relation looks like [this](https://typeorm.io/#/many-to-one-one-to-many-relations), but in the same [example](https://typeorm.io/#/many-to-one-one-to-many-relations), lets say for instance the `User` table's column `name` was also unique, now I want to reference that in the relation, which then the foreign key in photos would contain value of `name` and give it a different column name in `Photos` table other than `userId` to be e.g. `userName`, how exactly would i do that, am stuck and frankly hove no idea how to proceed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### For future reference

If you want your relation to point to a column other than `id`, you must add `referencedColumnName: '<column name here>'` to your `@JoinColumn()` options.

e.g:

```js
@Entity()
export class Photo {

    @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
    id: number;

    @Column()
    url: string;

    @ManyToOne(() => User, user => user.photos)
    @JoinColumn({ name: 'userName', referencedColumnName: 'name' })
    user: User;

}
```

Also, be careful of specifying the referencedColumnName from typeORM's point of view, not the real underlying driver column name.
For example, if you want to reference a column named `user_name`, but your entity's property uses camelCase `userName`, you must specify:

```js
referencedColumnName: 'userName'
```

if you specify the database column name instead, you will get errors complaining that typeORM could not find the referenced column in your entity definition.

Answer (score 1):

```
@Entity()
export class Photo {

    @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
    id: number;

    @Column()
    url: string;

    @ManyToOne(() => User, user => user.photos)
    @JoinColumn({ name: 'userName' }) // < -- add this line
    user: User;

}


@Entity()
export class User {

    @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
    id: number;

    @Column()
    name: string;

    @OneToMany(() => Photo, photo => photo.user)
    photos: Photo[];
}
```

Comment: This will still use the primary id of user in photos table, i want to use the name to be the value of the `userName` column in the photos table